# Fail to retrieve a wikidata item through SPARQL

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-api, wikidata-query-service

I tried to search and get the ID of a item with a certain label: `Teodor Bogdanov`. I can search this name successfully through [wikidata website](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q22277104). However, I failed to do so by searching through SPARQL. The code is [here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20distinct%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription%20WHERE%7B%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20%3Flabel%20%22Teodor%20Bogdanov%22.%0A%7D).

I also copied it here:

```
SELECT distinct ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription WHERE{  
  ?item ?label "Teodor Bogdanov".
}
```

The same thing happens for `Félix Anaut`

Could anyone help me fix this issue? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

THere are two issues in your query. The predicate in your triple pattern is a variable, while it should be a constant, `rdfs:label`. It asks about all items and properties linked to "Teodor Bogdanov". The second issue is the missing language tag. When these two are fixed, you get the following query

```
SELECT distinct ?item  {
  ?item rdfs:label "Teodor Bogdanov"@en .
}
```

For "Félix Anaut", while this spelling with an acute accent is used in English Wikipedia, that's not the case in Wikidata.

Comment: Or if we want it closer to the Wikidata search box with this query: `SELECT * WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "EntitySearch" .
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org" .     
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:search "Teodor Bogdanov" .
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:language "en" .
    ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item .
    ?num wikibase:apiOrdinal true . }
} 
ORDER BY ?num`

Comment: by the way, no need for `distinct` in your query

Comment: @UninformedUser, what should be the value of `mwapi:language` for any language, to serve the case like the second one here.?

Comment: I know that it's not possible, language param must be bound - nevertheless, the entity search does not only search on labels (also `skos:altLabel` I think?) and is closer to the search text field and is more fulltext index search like. Moreover, it works with the acute accent - note, this should just be an alternative to your common standard SPARQL query, indeed it  only works for Wikidata